# Parse-Server and HTTP/2 connections to APNS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-ios-sdk

We just got a message from Apple:

> On March 29, 2021, token and certificate-based HTTP/2 connections to the Apple Push Notification service must incorporate the new root certificate (AAACertificateServices 5/12/2020) which replaces the old GeoTrust Global CA root certificate. To ensure a seamless transition and to avoid push notification delivery failures, verify that both the old and new root certificates for the HTTP/2 interface are included in the Trust Store of each of your notification servers before March 29.
> Note that Apple Push Notification service SSL provider certificates issued to you by Apple do not need be to updated at this time.

I don't know how to find out if parse-server on this version have this or not?

Is there a risk that our push will stop working on this version of parse?

We are are running an older parse-server (2.6.5), No modifications or any other adapters other then what was in the package.

Comment: It actually depends on the version of @parse/push-adapter that you are running. Could you please check the version in your package.json?

Comment: https://www.zealousweb.com/how-to-send-http-2-based-push-notification-in-ios/

Check this.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo There is no pushadapter in the package.json, the only parse packages are "parse": "~1.9.1" and "parse-server": "~2.6.5"

Comment: Parse Server 2.6.5 uses parse-server-push-adapter 2.0.2, which uses api 3.0.0-alpha1, which has http2 support, so I believe you are good to go. I'd upgrade to the latest versions though.

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks correct that i don't need to do anything :-)